# Separating user input of time in C++

Tags: c++

I need to take a users input such as 10:35 and put it into a variable of hours and minutes. How can I do this using the colon as the separate for the two? This is how the assignment requires it be entered.

Example of what I am doing.

```
int main()
{
    char again = 'y';
    int userHours = 0;
    int userMinutes = 0;

    while (again == 'y')
    {
        cout << "Enter a time in 24-hour notation: ";
        cin >> userHours >> ":" >> userMinutes;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost had it:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int hours, minutes;
    char colon;
    std::cin >> hours >> colon >> minutes;
    std::cout << hours << " : " << minutes;

    return 0;
}
```

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4662d681057cec44)

Comment: Thanks, for some reason I was thinking it wouldn't work just by adding a variable for the colon.

Answer (score 1):

input and [convert](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) it to string , then split it into 2 strings , and then convert them in integers at last.

Answer (score 0):

Just take the input as a string. then **split** the string using [strtok()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/). insert the values into two variables. Before inserting [convert](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) the string values to integer.

Comment: Using strtok() in C++? That's horrible advice, really. Actually, strtok() is a bad idea even in C, because it is not thread-safe! The correct way to split strings is to use string streams or Boost (or for simple cases, do it manually with std::string's find and substr functions).